# When does kafka consumer get evicted from the group?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using spring kafka and want to know when does kafka consumer get evicted from the group. Does it get evicted when the processing time taken is more than the poll interval? If yes then isn't the purpose of the heartbeat to indicate the consumer is alive and if that happens then the consumer should never be evicted unless the process itself fails.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that the heartbeat thread tells the group that the consumer process is still alive. The reason for additionally considering a consumer to be gone when there is excessive time between polls is to prevent livelock.

Without this, a consumer might never poll, and so would take partitions without making any progress through them.

The question then is really why there is a heartbeat and session timeout. The heartbeat thread is actually doing other stuff (pre-fetching) but I assume the reason it is used to check that consumers are alive is that it is generally talking to the broker more frequently than the polling thread as the latter has to process messages, and so a failed consumer process will be spotted earlier.

In short there are 3 things that can trigger a rebalance - a change in number of partitions at the broker end, polling taking longer than `max.poll.interval.ms`, and gap between heartbeats longer than `session.timeout.ms`